# Is it possible to strongly type the return value of this function?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, eventemitter

I have a generic helper function that allows me to `await` events on any `EventEmitter`.

```js
import { type EventEmitter } from 'eventemitter3'

/** Returns a promise that resolves when the given event fires */
export const eventPromise = async (emitter: EventEmitter, event: string) =>
  new Promise<any>(resolve => {
    emitter.once(event, d => resolve(d))
  })
```

So I can await the next `foo` event as follows:

```js
await eventPromise(someEmitter, 'foo')
```

So far this works fine.

I'm using [eventemitter3](https://github.com/primus/eventemitter3), which gives me strongly typed events:

```js
type TestEvents = {
  foo: (payload: { bar: string }) => void
}

class TestEmitter extends EventEmitter<TestEvents> {
  test() {
    this.emit('foo', { bar: 'pizza' })
  }
}
```

So it seems like it should be possible for the return value of `eventPromise` to be strongly typed:

```js
const testEmitter = new TestEmitter()
const { bar } = await eventPromise(testEmitter, 'foo')
```

But this gives me an error, `Property 'bar' does not exist on type 'unknown'`. (See [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.3#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-N8iSlRjgihgxlA6AgaxgvgDyVRRhgAAtjv5mPhfLQZRBaD4tTq6GBgAAvYtqWiGmrB4MARkhqNZpDN3AeEhmovd0x2+099qIAc4hDt7v8Q5jKNb8HzxDIqjUuzU+EW0kOCmxY77UB8WdltESPP0AFoDlRxrBNHAAAbaqCXuCWCA9bYQSS8F5wUQzMZKS9rTAAa0wCBdkwS8W1Ec4LnQfwVQ8XwbxRTgD0vXFV2OdA7zEJMowuSw4F2aB-3w-Ak0iC8xU3HwgPgAArNY21EJRky+OAkzUKwoJsS9e29MDB2-OAAGVqHQAB5ZMiDFCVbiMTVZXlRVlVVdVEBDETk31CJMDWEBNTedkbhNSxmwtK0xBsYTunEpNJM7cwsBdCj3T0SyxIkqApN9RN-UDVFQ3DbooxjONBgTGYUzENMWEzOSczzNTug0zwIgAFgAJkrMK6wbPJOXNScErcmyPM7VRuyEkTrNs9EoAHc4rPczdRx8i0IKnQqkoNWd1AXJdUPkdDfHqorqopbdYr3cDxEuaDYKG9SU08eIgA).)

I've gone around in circles quite a bit trying to get `eventPromise` to return a strongly typed value. This is the closest I've gotten:

```js
export const eventPromise = async <
  T extends EventMap,
  K extends EventEmitter.EventNames<T> = EventEmitter.EventNames<T>,
>(
  emitter: EventEmitter<T>,
  event: K
) => {
  return new Promise<Parameters<T[K]>[0]>(resolve => {
    const listener = (payload: Parameters<T[K]>[0]) => resolve(payload)
    emitter.once(event, listener as EventEmitter.EventListener<T, K>)
  })
}
```

This compiles, but the return type is still `unknown`. (See [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.3&ssl=27&ssc=1&pln=28&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM72AN2MmAFKCAWwEtVg4BeOAQ1QE9kE4AeAKDjgBU5QYcAJqjgAlYEigCW6KCWQBzADRwAFADoNNKPNQAuWsnoBtALoBKKgD44mCCQGW2llR16kY-KPoCi2XN-dPFi5LRVcsHBgfPxgAkg9gKDVfSIA5GiJgVGDHC0prAG9XGHowCgBpKjgSsogAM14Y1yhgGABXKGQ4ZGAAdzgCYjJgFRbUCAAbbCs4Is5OJDR4CbJ%20HqgqlQEaGBp9PC0M1sTsriNyk0sjAAZzGbHJ7C2dmjNXTmBAxLUUBBGI3DKFboHCJWjCFL%20L5JSEwAAyq1BUGCynKljenAAvm9MWw2AB6fHcLIwPE1ChcEmw4TUOZwOoQCD6FRgGj0CYQGgCfQFOAAIy0%20hkcnkcGxM1s9jYuLYCAmdGElPQcQSGz4gghMRVQSVsRiqEKxRJKgsdM4MAAFmQ1J94ioAOQMiD25S8gVeOD2sAkABePpo9rFGLF0rxi3Q1Sp0KqPX6uu1iRNspQEbdWjFVRovRo8UakUGpHIKn4yuhykdjPtFkJrAAtANCGVYPQ4AADd2tuACCBZboQDAgVZwFDVUoUVttZAAa2QEF6yFbYZTk2Aag58hU7reBKJSDA9FrrJBAi7wDqcniJBT9MIRDzuFtqoAzHiBOJ5S1EPLUJrIgnka4sJcGOwjqsgQhwLC-5qAAajQKwCEBIFVMKChwAAPnADBEHykxhJwADCKD8CAA5rBBNCGJmhhOLMrjoDsJDMGALTniAwDclhMCyGhmG4SulEANx4h8MTpJkqAmvoACCUBQGyLBQdCyRiUc2RIWUBqWMJrjAmsJzBLwpEapBWrKbC4lZIpMTAZpljOO895RNwrhmDJckKUp8SeCpkQIiC6zWZEtlZMoITaSJcB6UiRGTjAKgAs5Xmqr5uCWepNkgei%20jIG0OGJDpHzuIZYEQclPkWWpQW4CFWkuPMTn6Fw%20HzBoahaDo0R-uZMSyTo1UwLVYWOJwbn8oyEzAEJkUoCVxngb%20ULed8lUSQNtX2fV8yJU1LWcHUyBdUtKWwv5%20nIhpoXcKEjmLCRMAAPz6ERD6ka5%20iWmQwmcFyAhnUic3kYtsQ9WkVWXXVjk7dwe30odpndctMIxP9gUQ8NsN3XwT1wC993vdUVqoIVw5MMAgMmeVK2qWtEObVDMS7Y5B1HSDSOpfCiJo5lmkY7dxHY89AtvaNH1EyTLREBA2Co4kFMLQjx0VTTVl0w5DXQ81zPIDjVPI35XNy%20j12Y8Lj1C69MCw78wA4-xk2UQTn3E649R1PLZVmezq2qzzWT0xrjMw9ruteydKOGxdfuoHzDVY6RON43w1tk3bE1TcgTvi5FkvS8A0kTBMstQJJiWh4j4dg7T0fZYTX2hmwb5yloFDIGprJ-IrbOqnRHzgNA8ByJ4dQ0J3xcAGLICwfWgfNFGGKY1HGJcvfzOomjaHocAz2NkoCN9IbhP3sBwEPiQj53esAMq7DATGr5wsasI5nAQ0ZQNwHBCFv9QqGiph2FcITFhoRM2S9HLODGnrdaIFlBJ1IhFLEkV8QACoUHvBQW2CAfIABW4gYCdlQBaCAbQJgnj5BQOQvB4gWjBPUQmFAGSFznCKek0AiB6AwW2Vsi55iYLPlAC%20FA35mkwZwe0iVay9BoYeQ4mRPCoHtPoSiy8uHiMkdIy0tZQAZDAJNWsFpKICEmlAJRqg2odS3io0weRrB7y4biPh3DeGcBQfiI%20kAT7kk-vBewP8uI8X-lhegOFJgYWHLg-BJNQCePgN4n2px34mS-n4muVQeClWEH-cJgDJiOQei5Bq%20gpzAHoPQrg0Tj5xLHNvbQeVIgAFkaBgA9sIbBeCEAwGsLSRy5xT5dBKWUhoXATBNXOCYJJCt17tU3sohedx8g2DsAIfJAw5HHBLsEcZI15hjIuJM%20eqiGoFLOBcRyczl4H0xJU2Jo4yhd2LuwBqGS57CBSYhaOsNKiZK7ulHIrhuncAOVk7irCAEhKAas6ZliLk2IlMs85qgX5wAsbM2p8h6m4CaS07wIA5RtDfCiAJYLgmhImPZIwuLuKjxgCwcoyhBnlMsCYRytiln2BuQPO5wjeqbyefMF5H93no0ct815vyqohABVUA48l5EGVOpHIlaIIoeK5eGeAetWb-hvoxBAwkZRAA).)

I honestly feel like none of these gymnastics should even be necessary - shouldn't the original function have enough information for TypeScript to infer its return type?

What am I missing?

---

**Clarification:** This should work generically with any EventEmitter, not just one that handles `TestEvents`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work with the code below.

I have extracted a definition of `TestMessages` more for convenience, the relevant differences with the code you have shown are in `eventPromise`, namely:

- I am actually returning from the promise callback;
- I have given a type to the returned promise.

`eventPromise` could be abstracted further in order to take emitters with arbitrary events in input, so it should become *generic*, but whether that is even needed already depends on specific requirements.

```
import { EventEmitter } from 'eventemitter3'

type TestMessages = {
    foo: { bar: string }
}

type TestEvents = {
    foo: (payload: TestMessages["foo"]) => void
}

class TestEmitter extends EventEmitter<TestEvents> {
    test() {
        this.emit('foo', { bar: 'pizza' })
    }
}

/** Returns a promise that resolves when the given event fires */
export const eventPromise = async (emitter: TestEmitter, event: keyof TestEvents) =>
    new Promise<TestMessages[typeof event]>(resolve => {
        return emitter.once(event, d => resolve(d))
    });

const testEmitter = new TestEmitter();

const { bar } = await eventPromise(testEmitter, 'foo');
```

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgUQG4FMB2NkmDGdKOAXzgDMoIQ4BydDbdPAogZloChOYBPMdHAAq6AM4wAsmNEBDAOZi4AXkSc46ihAgAuRHABGMqLvFRgmOaU4lufAcLE5GMUctUbNOuAAowM3gA2EDIAJroi4lKisgqiANoARORaCQC6AJTKAHxwqBDAIdbcAMYBMtEO4rj4hMToAB6EmCGuaFg4LLUAPBFO7aI5CGoahOLemUMeHjAAFsCiAHTM%20N60yRC0ADR6hsZ0YMAAXocytKTpw%20o2NpwA9ABU93AASugwAK5QmK4ycGBUeFEglmMngUDEEACGFcAHcZlg4LNBHJgIw4Ax2hRgODXPdbpwGpBYHBihBvvAMdgAAoA%20aCFTlXiYYo%20ZasPa9ars7aUmC6ADW6F4EHIlT62FEmSUWUucEw6BhcBp1DpPUcURiYjidnQIvRzlSWW8OMhGGy7im6nBHy%206M6RAWZOK6G8vO2IXNJqhLpC6QuHhI6QA3CUyeJEY4ubU3PLFZz7VBxiHOKTyTsjKQ3DIYTJ8Pr2srAS7Rh0akRtmstLRg5wgA)

Comment: Thanks! This works, but only for `TestEvents`. I need `eventPromise` to work with any `EventEmitter`.

Comment: @HerbCaudill  The main issue for a totally generic solution (i.e. not one parametrized on some fixed event types) is the shape of the *payload*, which is not known if we just pass an event *name* (see how it works with that `this.emit` for comparison).  That said, I'd be tempted to solve it by injecting a callback of the right type to do the "resolving" (in addition to the event name: and of course all variations in how to pack and pass these are possible), but I am *not* familiar enough with 'eventemitter3' to be sure there is no cleaner approach with the provided types and classes...

Comment: But it seems like in my attempt above TypeScript has all the information it needs to deterministically infer the shape of the payload: It knows the type `T` of the event map, and it knows the key `K` in that event map, which is the name of the event. From that information it can determine the type of the first argument of the function that corresponds to the event name.

Comment: @HerbCaudill  Well, no, the first argument is an `Emitter`, and the first type argument of that is "the valid event types", which is again just the type of valid event *names*, no connection to *payloads*. -- Meanwhile I have been looking at docs and examples: I am finding out that the `Context` parameter of `Emitter` might have been introduced in the library expressly to support specifying the type of the payload...  I will finish double-checking that I am getting that correctly, then will rewrite my answer (might take few hours, I am busy right now...).

Comment: @HerbCaudill  I might be wrong but I have come to the conclusion that **a totally generic solution is *not* possible here**, the show-stopper being that the library in question does *not* tie in any way the type arguments of the EventEmitter (which just define the valid event names) with the type of arguments of any EventListener.

Comment: Indeed, even *restricting* and leveraging the first type parameter of EventEmitter to be an *object type* with properties whose name is a valid event name (as usual), and whose type is the type of the *sole argument* (the "payload") that any listeners for that emitter are expected to take, that may solve the problem of a "generic enough" `eventPromise`, but then the problem remains that `EventEmitter.emit` would still *not* check that its argument satisfies the payload type associated with the event name... and we'd find ourselves rewriting the whole library to fill that essential gap.

Comment: Would you anyway be interested in that "generic enough" solution, despite the disclaimers? -- Incidentally, I am having serious doubts on what you are trying to do overall: an `await eventPromise(...)` is destined to never return, certainly not in a single-threaded context, unless one preliminarily schedules an `emit` with `setTimeout`...?

Comment: This is a useful pattern in any event-driven system where things happen asynchronously. The event might fire because of a timeout, because of network activity, because something was loaded from storage, or because a user did something. See [here](https://github.com/local-first-web/auth/blob/687cd1f599e21a4924abaf1aaf78de9bc04f1645/packages/auth-syncserver/src/test/SyncServer.test.ts#L35-L36) for a real-world example.

Comment: > "the library in question does not tie in any way the type arguments of the EventEmitter (which just define the valid event names) with the type of arguments of any EventListener"

I'm not sure what you mean by this. TypeScript enforces the payload type, based on the event name, both when you emit an event and when you listen for an event. [Playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WGG1VW)

Comment: @HerbCaudill I disagree on that pattern, but never mind, you are right that your example works (or seems to work): my apologies for not having had much time, I will see if I can parse that and put together a better answer by the week-end...

Comment: @HerbCaudill  I am sorry but I am not finding a way that is any better than what I have proposed above as a "generic enough" solution.  --  Eventually, I am pretty convinced there is a fundamental design issue with the library itself: so, despite my working knowledge of TS is not that sophisticated and I cannot totally exclude a reasonable work-around exists (or that I am not missing anything), given how little code it is, I'd simply fix/rewrite the lib...

Answer (score 0):

Extending on @Julio Di Egidio's answer, you can use the Parameters utility type to avoid creating another type.

```
import ValidEventTypes, { EventEmitter } from 'eventemitter3'

/** Returns a promise that resolves when the given event fires */
async function eventPromise<T extends ValidEventTypes, U extends keyof 
TestEvents>(emitter: T, event: U) {
  const res = new Promise<Parameters<TestEvents[U]>[0]>(resolve => {
    return emitter.once(event, (d) => resolve(d))
  })
  return res
}

type TestEvents = {
   foo: (payload: { bar: string }) => void
}

class TestEmitter extends EventEmitter<TestEvents> {
  test() {
    this.emit('foo', { bar: 'pizza' })
  }
}

const testEmitter = new TestEmitter()
const { bar } = await eventPromise(testEmitter, 'foo')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow & thanks for working on this! See my comment on @Julio's answer - I need `eventPromise` to work with any `EventEmitter`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong, but regarding [official documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) it seems that Parameters  will always return the unknow type when passed a generic type. Reason why it is not possible to get exact type for eventPromise() function by this way.[image]

Comment: Well, in the case of `<T>(arg: T) => T`, `T` _is_ unknown. But`Parameters<>` can definitely give you the types of the arguments when you give it a specific implementation - [Playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WKbM8m)

Comment: Good analysis, except that in your playground example you used `Parameters<typeof f1>` instead `Parameters<<T>(arg: T) => T>` ; according Parameters type documentation. it seems that it is rather `Parameters<<T>(arg: T) => T>` which fits with this issue regarding used events definition.

Comment: Hope this will be helpful for the rest.